# How to make select boxes span the remaining width of div, rails 4, bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4, Bootstrap 3

I have handful of select boxes that are displayed in a column, with the input labels next to the select dropdown box.  The problem is, it looks like garbage:

[image]

How can I force the select box to fill the remaining space within the div, regardless of the length of the text length of the selection options?  I want all of the boxes to be right-aligned.

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :age %>
        <%= f.select :age, options_for_select(%w[18-20 20-25 25-30 30-35 35-40 40+]), class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :ethnicity %>
        <%= f.select :ethnicity, options_for_select(%w[White Asian Black Hispanic Other]), class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :height %>
        <%= f.select :height, options_for_select(%w[<5ft 5'0"-5'5" 5'6"-5'9" +5'10"]), class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :eyes %>
        <%= f.select :eyes, options_for_select(%w[Blue Green Brown]), class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should display div.form-group as table and the label tag and select tag as table-cells and force their widths like this:

```
.control-group {
    display:table;
}

.control-group label,
.control-group select {
    display: table-cell;
}

.control-group label {
    width:1%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding-right:10px;
}

.control-group select {
    width:99%;
}
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HhCBK/

Comment: Thanks lulian, that worked perfectly! Do you also know how I would go about making the select boxes the same width, while keeping them right-aligned in the div (basically trimming the left side of the select dropdowns)?